# Search for the value from ComboBox, then write the value from a Textbox to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet in my workplace, where we are making pallets. I made a userform where I have **5 ComboBoxes** with **5 TextBoxes**. When we have a new order I want the macro to get the value from the ComboBoxes and search for the name in the field "E7:E1347" and insert the number from the TextBox to column M next to the searched pallet. Example:
I want to order 10 pcs of TestPallet. I type the TestPallet in ComboBox1 and type 10 to TextBox6. After I hit the INSERT button I want the macro to search for the name and insert the number from the textbox to column M.

I have a workaround for now, but it is really slow. I made a sheet where if I type something in the boxes it sores there, but the program recalculates every time I am hiting a key to write the name of the pallet and it is quite slow. I feel like, it would be quicker this way, if its possible to make.

The code I have so far: (everything that is commented in the code works)

```
Public Sub Import_Click()

Dim palety, skracovanie, harmonogram As Worksheet
Set palety = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("palety")
Set skracovanie = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("skracovanie")
Set harmonogram = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("harmonogram")

Dim i  As Long
 
For i = 7 To 1347
 If InStr(Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value, Me.ComboBox1.Value) Then 
 Sheets(1).Range("M" & i).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
Next

'Sheets("palety").Select
'ActiveSheet.Range("M:M").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">=1"

'név
'palety.Range("E1347:E3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 '   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'kód vstupného reziva
'palety.Range("AA1347:AA3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 '   :=False, Transpose:=False

'kód palety
'palety.Range("C1347:C3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 '   :=False, Transpose:=False
'harmonogram fulre
'palety.Range("C7:C1341").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'harmonogram.Cells(5, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'kód prírezov
'palety.Range("G1347:G3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 '   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'méretek + darabszám
'palety.Range("H1347:K3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 '   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'poznámka
'palety.Range("BW1347:BW3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 '   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'objem celkom
'palety.Range("N1347:N3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'výťaž
'palety.Range("AC1347:AC3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'príprava
'palety.Range("Q1347:Q3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False

'spotreba času na 100 ks
'palety.Range("R1347:R3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 17).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False

'prírez V szog
'palety.Range("F1347:F3925").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'skracovanie.Cells(3, 24).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False
    

'Rows("3:100").Select
'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("skracovanie").Sort.SortFields.Clear
'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("skracovanie").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
'    "F3:F100"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
'    xlSortNormal
'With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("skracovanie").Sort
'    .SetRange Range("A3:X100")
 '   .Header = xlGuess
 '   .MatchCase = False
  '  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
   ' .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    '.Apply
'End With
```

Thanks for the help in advance. Even if this is not possible, just saying "this is not possible" is a huge help.

Comment: Hi! Sounds like a good idea you've got going there. Share a [MCVE] which will help us to help you (as we will be able to work out where you might have gone wrong). Without any code you won't attract many answers or suggestions via comments.

Comment: How have you populated the combobox?

Comment: @SamuelEverson Added the code to the original question. Sorry I am new to this website

Comment: @norie  Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("palety").Range("E7:E1341").Value I used this on UserForm Initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Single Combobox/Textbox

Since you've populated the combobox from the range E7:E1341 we can use it's ListIndex property to get the row of the value selected and from that the appropriate value from column M.

```vb
Dim idx As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
     
    idx = ComboBox1.ListIndex

    If idx <> -1 Then 
        lngRow = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 7
        Worksheets("palety").Range("M" & lngRow).Value = TextBox1.Value
    End If
```

### Multiple Comboxes/Textboxes

If you have multiple comboboxes/textboxes named sequentially, e.g. ComboBox1/TextBox1, ComboBox2/TextBox2 etc, and populated in the same way, then you could use something like this to put all the values in column M.

```vb
Dim idx As Long
Dim idxList As Long
Dim lngRow As Long

    For idx = 1 To 5
        idxList = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & idx).ListIndex
        If idxList <> -1 Then
            lngRow = idxList + 7
            Worksheets("palety").Range("M" & lngRow).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & idx).Value
        End If
    Next idx
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I assigned it to the button, but when I try it, the number from the textbox disappears and its not appearing in the M column at the pallet I chose. Had some leftover code in that cell, deleted it and still nothing. Or I might done something wrong? Tried to assign it to the combobox, but now it is empty

Comment: Sorry, I got things the wrong way round - I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked just fine. I have 1 more question: do I have to do this code for every single combobox or is there a way to go through all of them?

Comment: Which column should the values for the other comboboxes/textboxes go?

Comment: Its the same: Other comboboxes are populated from the same field. The other textboxes should go to M column as well

Comment: I've updated the answer with something that should work.

Comment: Tried the code with 2 comboboxes and 2 textboxes, but now the rest of the code is going wild. The AutoFilter part gives me a total white part of the sheet. Shows me only the cells without any kind of value (including 0). Thus the copy doesnt work. It worked before.

Comment: The code I posted shouldn't affect any other code, where are you actually putting it?

Comment: Import button, as before. Rest of the code was signed as comment, cause it worked. It even worked with 1 entry. Now that there is 2 entries its doing this. Error I am getting is Run-time error 1004  "There no such cell." (translated from Hungary)

Comment: So where did you put the code I posted  for multiple comboxes/ttextboxes?

Comment: I always put it in the Import Button. To the code I provided in the original question.

Comment: I'm sorry but all the code I posted does is put values in column B, if that's affecting the other code then there could be something wrong with the other code. What's the other code meant to do anyway?

Comment: The second part is meant to filter the "palety" sheet in the M column. After that what cells are visible copy specifed cells value to sheet "skracovanie" (Kód to code column on skracovanie, Név to Name).Those comments are there just so I know what I am copying in that part of the code. I can provide a picture if needed.

Comment: Ok, it works. Did not realized I had the wrong names for textboxes. Fixed it, and works like  a dream. Thank You very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
Dim i  as long
     
  For i =7 to 1347
     If Instr(Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value, me.combobox1.value) then Sheets(1).Range("M" & i).value=me.textbox6.value    
   next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i try to run Your code i get the error message "Next without For"

Comment: Check it now :) If it works upvote my suggestion! it was for instead of For

Comment: Tried the new version, but is does nothing. Waited for like 2 minutes (just to check that my computer is slow), but nothing happened.

Comment: Are the information on sheet 1? If not change accordingly

Comment: change sheets(1) to activesheet

Comment: We already solved this, other code worked, which is marked as answer