# Listing names in a dropdown list, when any part of the name is typed in a ComboBox on a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a list of pallet names. I also have userform and 7 comboboxes with the names in it. Comboboxes are populated from a range like this:

Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("palety").Range("E7:E1341").Value

Right now I have to type the exact name of the pallet to be able to search for it. I want to just type a part of it and have it appear in the dropdown list. Tried this code:

```
Private Sub cboProgrammeName_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Set ws = Sheets("XXX")
x = ws.Range("ProgrammeNameList").Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
str = Me.cboProgrammeName.Value
If str <> "" Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        If InStr(LCase(x(i, 1)), LCase(str)) > 0 Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    Me.cboProgrammeName.List = dict.keys
Else
    Me.cboProgrammeName.List = x
End If
Me.cboProgrammeName.DropDown
End Sub
```

The code itself worked, but my insert and copy macro went wild, and stopped working properly. Inserted it to the wrong row, and thus copied the wrong pallet. I added the code to ComboBox1_change

For example:

we have a pallet with name TestPallet 123, PalletTest 123, 123 Test. When I type in 123 i would like to have appear every pallet that contain 123 in it.

This is my code, it searches the chosen pallet from ComboBoxes, then inserts the number from TextBoxes. After that autofilters the field and copies the visible cells into another sheet. When I tried the code above the search and insert part did not worked.

```
Public Sub Import_Click()
Dim palety As Worksheet
Dim skracovanie As Worksheet
Dim harmonogram As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set palety = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("palety")
Set skracovanie = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("skracovanie")
Set harmonogram = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("harmonogram")

palety.Range("M7:M1331").ClearContents

Dim idx As Long
Dim idxList As Long
Dim lngRow As Long

For idx = 1 To 7
    idxList = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & idx).ListIndex
    If idxList <> -1 Then
        lngRow = idxList + 7
        Worksheets("palety").Range("M" & lngRow).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & idx).Value
    End If
Next idx

skracovanie.Activate
skracovanie.Range("A3:M100").ClearContents
skracovanie.Range("P3:Q100").ClearContents
skracovanie.Range("X:X").ClearContents

Sheets("palety").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("M:M").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">=1"

'név
palety.Range("E1347:E4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'kód vstupného reziva
palety.Range("V1347:V4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False

'kód palety
palety.Range("C1347:C4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
'harmonogram fulre
Worksheets("harmonogram").Range("A5:A62").ClearContents
palety.Range("C7:C1341").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
harmonogram.Cells(5, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'kód prírezov
palety.Range("G1347:G4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'méretek
palety.Range("H1347:J4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
   
'darabszám
palety.Range("M1347:M4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'poznámka
palety.Range("BI1347:BI4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'objem celkom
palety.Range("N1347:N4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'výťaž
palety.Range("X1347:X4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
'príprava
palety.Range("P1347:P4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'spotreba času na 100 ks
palety.Range("Q1347:Q4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 17).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'prírez V szog
palety.Range("F1347:F4000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
skracovanie.Cells(3, 24).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

[my code that was solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056354/search-for-the-value-from-combobox-then-write-the-value-from-a-textbox-to-a-cel); [code copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076069/searchable-combo-box-with-a-list-of-sugggestion-on-a-userform?)

Comment: Some hints: Note that any variable declared without explicit datatype is of type Variant. Thus your first declaration line should be `Dim palety As Worksheet, skracovanie As Worksheet, harmonogram As Worksheet`. Furthermore try to fully qualify your range references and to avoid detours via selections, refer directly to the range objects :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hints :) Changed the first part of my code according to what You wrote. But I do not fully understand the second part of the comment about the selections. If You mean the copy part I found it on an another forum (can't remember where). The selections I only need them for deleting values and for the AutoFilter.

Comment: Apply methods like e.g. `.ClearContents` directly instead of using 3 code lines: `skracovanie.Range("A3:M100").ClearContents`. See also [How to avoid Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10718179?r=SearchResults&s=1|45.0718#10718179)@gandalf96

Comment: Thanks for the tips, changed my code according to those. :)